# How do I setup cipher suites in Mule

Tags: ssl, https, mule, tls1.2, anypoint-studio

I am using Anypoint Studio 6.1 and Mule 3.8.1 and am trying to configure HTTPS.

My problem is in the documentation it states that there is a file called tls-default.conf which contains the cipher suites, but I cannot find this file.  I can only find the conf folder in the .mule directory but this is outside my project folder and looks to be Anypoint Studio configuration that would be local to my machine(not sure if I've misunderstood how this can be deployed).

Where is this file and how do I specify cipher suites?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to control the Ciphers/TLS settings: 1) Connector/Endpoint Specific settings 2) Mule Runtime (tls-default.conf) 3) JVM level

For #1 use

```
<tls:context name="TLS_Context" enabledProtocols="TLS1.2" enabledCipherSuites="TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384" doc:name="TLS Context"/>
```

And then refer to that configuration within your HTTP connector.
This example is using a Global HTTP Listener Cfg

```
<http:listener-config doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" port="${https.port}"  protocol="HTTPS">
<tls:context enabledProtocols="TLSv1.2" enabledCipherSuites="TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"/>
</http:listener-config>
```

For #2, withing Anypoint Studio the Runtime is embedded therefore you would need to make that cfg in the plugin directory
for example: [Anypoint-Studio-Plugin-Directory]/org.mule.tooling.server.[runtime-version-number]/mule/conf

For #3 - just follow the generic Java security configuration guidelines from Oracle

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking at the Anypoint studio workspace. You need to look at the studio installation path for the file.

(AnypointStudio_Installation_Path)\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.3.8.1.ee_6.1.1.201609121705\mule\conf